# Creating Windows Desktop Icon in CMake + CPack + NSIS

Tags: windows-installer, cmake, nsis

I'm using NSIS package generator in CMake 2.8.1 to distribute a Qt application. Everything is working fine... except the use of `CPACK_CREATE_DESKTOP_LINKS` to create a desktop link to the application.

I've looked through the [CMake source](http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob;f=Source/CPack/cmCPackNSISGenerator.cxx;h=ad773862b329260994d7dbb9a559e4964f3f53b2;hb=HEAD) (including it's own "bootstrap" installation definition for windows), and as far as I can tell I'm doing the same thing.

Here's the relevant section of my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
set(CPACK_GENERATOR NSIS)
set(CPACK_NSIS_PACKAGE_NAME "${EWS_APP_NAME}")
set(CPACK_NSIS_DISPLAY_NAME "${EWS_APP_NAME}")
set(CPACK_NSIS_CONTACT "${EWS_EMAIL}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_EXECUTABLES "${EXE_TARGET_NAME}" "${EWS_APP_NAME}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY "${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}-${EWS_VERSION}")

# this works
set(CPACK_NSIS_MENU_LINKS "${EWS_WEBSITE}" "Homepage for ${EWS_APP_NAME}")

# this doesn't
set(CPACK_CREATE_DESKTOP_LINKS "${EXE_TARGET_NAME}")

# Icon in the add/remove control panel. Must be an .exe file 
set(CPACK_NSIS_INSTALLED_ICON_NAME bin\\\\${EXE_TARGET_NAME}.exe)

set(CPACK_NSIS_URL_INFO_ABOUT "${EWS_WEBSITE}")
set(CPACK_NSIS_HELP_LINK "${EWS_WEBSITE}")
```

Any ideas or debugging tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try adding this to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set (CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH "ON")
```

I think that should add a page after the license that gives the option to add the install directory to the path, and add an option to create desktop links.

Answer (score 7):

One work-around I figured out is to use `CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS` and `CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_UNINSTALL_COMMANDS` to insert the link creation/deletion commands directly.

```
set(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS "
    CreateShortCut \\\"$DESKTOP\\\\${EWS_APP_NAME}.lnk\\\" \\\"$INSTDIR\\\\bin\\\\${EXE_TARGET_NAME}.exe\\\"
")

set(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_UNINSTALL_COMMANDS "
    Delete \\\"$DESKTOP\\\\${EWS_APP_NAME}.lnk\\\"
")
```

I'd much rather use the more general (and cross-platform?) `CPACK_CREATE_DESKTOP_LINKS` setting, so any followup ideas are appreciated. But this works in a pinch.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the following macro to add links both to the program files menu to the desktop

```
macro(prepareNSIS_Link linkName appName params)
 #prepare start menu links
 LIST(APPEND CPACK_NSIS_CREATE_ICONS_EXTRA "  CreateShortCut '$SMPROGRAMS\\\\$STARTMENU_FOLDER\\\\${linkName}.lnk' '$INSTDIR\\\\bin\\\\${appName}.exe' '${params}'")
 LIST(APPEND CPACK_NSIS_DELETE_ICONS_EXTRA "  Delete '$SMPROGRAMS\\\\$START_MENU\\\\${linkName}.lnk'")

 #prepare desktop links
 LIST(APPEND CPACK_NSIS_CREATE_ICONS_EXTRA  "  CreateShortCut '$DESKTOP\\\\${linkName}.lnk' '$INSTDIR\\\\bin\\\\${appName}.exe' '${params}'")
 LIST(APPEND CPACK_NSIS_DELETE_ICONS_EXTRA  "  Delete '$DESKTOP\\\\${linkName}.lnk'")
endmacro()
```

To create a link to for `[installFolder]/bin/app.exe -some -parameters` call it as:

```
prepareNSIS_Link("My application" "app" "-some -parameters")
```

Once you set up all your links be nice and replace semicolons with new lines:

```
  string (REPLACE ";" "\n" CPACK_NSIS_CREATE_ICONS_EXTRA "${CPACK_NSIS_CREATE_ICONS_EXTRA}")
  string (REPLACE ";" "\n" CPACK_NSIS_DELETE_ICONS_EXTRA "${CPACK_NSIS_DELETE_ICONS_EXTRA}")
```

Answer (score 2):

For others who come across this thread, there's the *CPACK_NSIS_CREATE_ICONS_EXTRA* and *CPACK_NSIS_DELETE_ICONS_EXTRA* CMake variables which can be used to create arbitrary shortcuts (Start menu, desktop, etc.). The delete side of things can have a small gotcha, but it's still a relatively easy and flexible way to get shortcuts where you want them. The added bonus is that you can also add command-line arguments if required. [This short article](http://crascit.com/2015/08/07/cmake_cpack_nsis_shortcuts_with_parameters/) explains how to use these variables to create and delete Start menu items and includes links to documentation for other useful NSIS variables. It should be easy enough to use the approach for desktop shortcuts with the information presented there.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't need to quote ${EXE_TARGET_NAME} as it is a string.

Comment: True enough (just a habit on my part), but doesn't affect the result.